# Angular(5) - Login button not changing to Logout on successful login

Tags: angular, rxjs, auth0

I'm using Auth0's API to handle user management. Everything is working as intended - On `Login()` it properly stores local. On `Logout()` it properly removes them.

However, the actual `Login` button is not becoming `Logout` automatically on success - It is when I hard-refresh the page, but not directly. I believe this is an issue with my binding?

**Header component**

```
  authenticated: boolean; // Wasn't sure how else to filter in front-end

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated()
  }



  login() {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

**HTML For Header**

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link waves-light" *ngIf="!authenticated" mdbRippleRadius (click)="login()"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">Log In</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link waves-light" *ngIf="authenticated" mdbRippleRadius (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">Log Out</span></a>
  </li>
```

The docs said to use `auth.isAuthenticated()` which would call the function from the service

```
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    // Check whether the current time is past the
    // access token's expiry time
    const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }
```

I was thinking perhaps I should append `this.authenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated()` to the end of each `login()/logout()` function in the header component, but I'm feeling like I'm going the wrong direction with this.

Welcome any input.

**Update**

Modifying `logout()` to call `this.authenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated()` did resolve the issue for it, but Login is still not becoming Log Out until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `authenticated` as a property getter:

```
public get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for poor reply, but would this then become the requirement of the `*ngIf`?

Comment: Your `*ngIf` would stay the same.

Comment: Wow, sure enough that worked perfectly. Thanks for this! I like this approach. I wasn't aware about this capacity.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you’re only updating your variable on init. That’s why you only see the changes when you refresh. If you do

```
login() {
this.authService.login();
this.authenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated()
  }
```

Inside the login method it should work.

Comment: Thanks for speedy reply. I actually tested it, and on `logout` that works, but `login` I am not seeing the proper results. Perhaps because it is running BEFORE the login() of authServ happens? How could I make it wait until success?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer. Did you try as I’m suggesting?